# Put the line count into the file name

Tags: bash

I want to put the number of lines (line count) in a file into the name of the file.  So if a file contains the two lines

```
moon
sun
```

I want to set the file name to

```
filename_2.txt
```

I tried using `awk` to rename the file like this:

```
awk 'END{print NR}' filename_$(NR).txt
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
# !/bin/sh -

for file in ./*.txt; do
    echo mv -v -- "$file" "${file%.txt}_$(<"$file" wc -l).txt"
done
```

Note: Remove *`echo`* if you were happy with the result.